# Temporary Doctrine2 fixtures for testing with phpunit

Tags: testing, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit, fixtures

I have an application built on Symfony2 + Doctrine2 which I want to create some tests for (using phpunit).

For example if I want to test a **unique** validator against a record in the DB, I want to create a record I can work with, but after the test I don't need it anymore. So is there a way to create temporary (or virtual) fixtures or do I have to manually create and delete them?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [Doctrine DataFixture](https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures#readme) and put this code in your setUp method of a unit test class:

```
$loader = new Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Loader;
$loader->loadFromDirectory('/path/to/MyDataFixtures');
$purger = new Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\ORMPurger($em);
$executor = new Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\ORMExecutor($em, $purger);
$executor->execute($loader->getFixtures());
```

You can refer to the docs to see how create DataFixture classes.

Here is a good example of how to do it: [Symfony 2 + Doctrine 2 + PHPUnit 3.5: Serialization of closure exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366592/symfony-2-doctrine-2-phpunit-3-5-serialization-of-closure-exception)

PS: I assume you have a working $em (EntityManager) in this example.

Comment: Or,

$loader = new \Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\DataFixtures\ContainerAwareLoader(static::$kernel->getContainer());

If you need to use a fixture that implements ContainerAwareInterface.

Also, thanks! Just used this answer.

Comment: Does the PRMPurger really require an $em for it's initiation?

Comment: what's the best way to load all fixtures from src directories?